# Fatal error with spl_autoload

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoload-call

I have this piece of code here to load classes automatically:

```
<?php
$test = [
            'includeDirs' => [
                'interfacesDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'interfaces'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
                'abstractsDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'abstracts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
                'classesDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            ],
            'includeExtensions' => [
                'classExtension' => '.class.php',
                'abstractExtension' => '.abstract.php',
                'interfaceExtension' => '.interface.php'
            ]
        ];

set_include_path('.');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $test['includeDirs']));

spl_autoload_extensions(implode(',', $test['includeExtensions']));
spl_autoload_register();

$streamFactory = new StreamFactory();
```

But i allways get the following error:
Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class StreamFactory could not be loaded in     C:\Users\Test\PhpstormProjects\Test\test.php on line 24

When i check the paths that get set in the include path, they are correct.
Can someone give me a hint, why that error gets thrown?

Comment: Where is the location of StreamFactory class? it is `classes`?

Comment: Yes it is here: C:\Users\Test\PhpstormProjects\Test\classes\stream_factory.class.php

Comment: One more question, what is the namespace that StreamFactory uses?

Comment: I didn't set up any name space. It is all global.

Comment: Have you tried `$streamFactory = new \StreamFactory();`?

Comment: I did right now, sadly it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of `StreamFactory` class  to `stream_factory` and instantiate it with `$streamFactory = new stream_factory();` or rename the file 'stream_factory.class.php' to `StreamFactory.class.php`.

`index.php`

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$test = [
  'includeDirs' => [
    'interfacesDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'interfaces'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'abstractsDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'abstracts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'classesDir' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
  ],
  'includeExtensions' => [
    'classExtension' => '.class.php',
    'abstractExtension' => '.abstract.php',
    'interfaceExtension' => '.interface.php'
  ]
];

set_include_path('.');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $test['includeDirs']));

spl_autoload_extensions(implode(',', $test['includeExtensions']));
spl_autoload_register();

try {
  $streamFactory = new \stream_factory();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

`classes/stream_factory.class.php`

```
<?php
class stream_factory {
  function __construct() {
    echo "Hello from " . __CLASS__;
  }
}
```